# Need I ask permission to edit an answer to add a minor improvement?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

On this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/109858/2704) on English Language Learners, I read the existing answers and decided that an answer of my own wouldn't add much. The only thing I thought I could add to the most highly upvoted answer was some images. So I did in the form of an [edit](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/49002). (I don't yet have edit privileges on this site).

Ultimately, the edit was rejected with an auto-comment and a custom comment.

- > This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.
- > You should first leave a comment to the author of the Q asking his permission. The author has not disappeared, so there's a good chance he will reply.

The former, although I can see where it has come from, I disagree with. I don't think the edits are *drastic*, and I believe I haven't modified the `goals of the post's owner`. I'm not too concerned with this rejection.

The latter is more interesting, however. If I think I can make a post better, is there really a need to ask permission to edit? Ignoring the outcome of this particular edit, if I have a link or image that I think can ameliorate a post in the future, should I hold back?

---

In particular, I found the following information on the Help page.
*Emphasis mine*

> Edits are expected to be substantial and to **leave the post better than you found it**. Common reasons for edits include:
>
> - ...
> - To **add related resources** or hyperlinks

Have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: Adding images to a question, that were not provided by the author, isn't an edit that will be approved.  Both reasons are legitimate reasons to not approve your edit

Comment: @Ramhound, in which case, why? What is special about images (that are otherwise a good edit) which means that they should be declined?

Comment: If the author supplied the images, adding them inline, is a valid edit.  Adding an image that the author didn't supply changes the question, and might deviate, from what the author actually is attempting to say.  An edit that's declined by multiple people, isn't a valid edit, so you can't say it's otherwise a valid edit.  The reviewers have over 150 answers each, this isn't a case of, the reviewers not approving a edit that should be approve.

Comment: Quite simply in this case, it *doesn't* change the post, it simply adds visuals to the text. In particular, note that I was editing an answer, not a question. I might think differently of a question.

Comment: @Ramhound I disagree and I think it really depends on the site. Many of the sites I'm on would be fine with someone adding images to an answer. Remember that answers aren't really owned by the original poster... they are community content and editing them is allowed. They aren't magical little entities that are inviolate.

Comment: @Catija They *are* in fact owned by the post author.  Yes, they *can* be edited in certain ways, but that doesn't remove the author's ownership of that post.

Comment: @Servy But the OP doesn't get total say in the content. Editing the content is part of the moderation function of the site... and to that end, no, they don't "own" the post.

Comment: @Catija The only exception to their total control over the actual content is that they can't vandalize their own post.  Yes, editing is part of the moderation of the site but *it doesn't remove ownership from the author of the post*.  It is still *their* post, that they *own*.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of posts and help the *original author's content* be better understood by others, not to change that content

Comment: @Servy but we're not arguing different things, we just think about it in slightly different ways. This edit did "improve the presentation of the post and help the original author's content be better understood"... which is what I was saying.

Comment: @Catija So then say *that*, because you *didn't* say that.  Rather than saying the author of the post can't object you you changing the content of the post, say that this edit doesn't change the content of the post.  Don't say that the author doesn't own the post when they unambiguously own the post, as is specifically laid out in the terms of service.

Comment: I think I have the same view of ownership as Catija. Although it's my name at the bottom of the post, I don't think of the whole post as "mine", more just acknowledgement of contribution. I consider the post "property" of the SE community after I press "Post". The IP might be mine, but ownership of the post itself I relinquish.

Comment: @Servy Have you seen my answer?

Comment: @JamesWebster And that's wrong.  The author of the post *does* own the content, legally speaking.  It is still theirs.  They are licensing SE (and everyone else) to be able to share the content, and allow derived works to be created from it (as long as it is cited appropriately), but the author still *owns* the content.

Comment: @Catija I have.  That doesn't make your comments on the question any less wrong.

Comment: @Servy, my comment wasn't intended to be a strict legal interpretation, rather a practical one, a description of how I (and others in my experience) approach SE

Comment: @JamesWebster And you're welcome to act as if you don't own your own posts.  You're even welcome to legally give up your own ownership rights for your own posts and put them into the public domain.  What you *aren't* allowed to do is act as if anyone else doesn't own their own posts, because they do.

Comment: @Servy, we seem to have gone off on a tangent. Would you have approved the edit? Would you encourage similar edits in the future?

Comment: @JamesWebster I would say no.  You're adding your own original content to the post.  That is not what suggested edits are for.

Comment: @Servy: I think it is a misunderstanding to say that "it is still their post, that they own [...] as is specifically laid out in the terms of service". My understanding is that users don't own *posts* on SE; they own *content* that they have contributed. For example, if someone edits your post to add some information, you don't own that information just because it's in "your" post. Also, any edit changes the content of the post to some degree.

Comment: @sumelic It's not appropriate to edit someone else's post to add your own original content to it, so the edit you're describing isn't an acceptable edit according to the rules.  Edits are there to change the presentation *of the author's content*, not to add their own original content.

Comment: @Servy: That might be true. In that case, the right way to argue that is to cite SE rules for editing, not to reference the unrelated point that users retain IP rights to the content they contribute.

Comment: @sumelic It's not unrelated; I brought it up in response to someone else saying that users do not own the posts that they post to SE.  That's wrong, and I corrected that.  I have *also* stated that edits are not allowed to add original content to the post, so saying I haven't brought it up isn't the case.  I mean, your comment just a few minutes ago is in response to my comment stating precisely that the editing rules for SE state that you aren't supposed to be adding original content via edits.

Comment: @Servy, the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) pages disagree with you. `this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia`, `If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!`, `If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.`

Comment: @JamesWebster That doesn't say that you can add your own original content via edits.  And of course if you continue to read on in the help center to where it describes what types of edits are and are not appropriate, it will spell that out.  The improvements that it is referring to in that summary is improvements in presentation, not changes to content.

Comment: Indeed, I quote one of those points in particular in my question: `To add related resources or hyperlinks`

Comment: @Servy: Users don't "own" *posts. Posts* are part of the page on Stack Exchange's site, owned by Stack Exchange. When a user makes a post, the user contributes content to Stack Exchange and licences it. The terms of service state that the user doesn't give up their rights to this content by contributing it to Stack Exchange. They don't say that the user gets control over what content Stack Exchange displays in the post on Stack Exchange's site.

Comment: @Servy: For example, users don't have a right to just delete all of their posts, even if they want to.

Comment: @JamesWebster You're not adding a reference to a related resource.

Comment: `All edits are saved and tracked in a public revision history with attribution to each editor` I interpret this as "Each user retains their own IP, however the post is un-owned"

Comment: No, I'm adding "a related resource". In the edit in question, images are the related resource.

Comment: @sumelic Yes, technically the users own the content of the post, not the post itself.  The rules of the site itself however dictate that posts are there to represent the content of their owner, and that edits to the posts are there to improve the presentation of that owner's content, not to add original content; the site's own rules dictates that the author of a post is kept in control over its content, the site will however exercise the licence that the author posts the content under to prevent vandalism of it.

Comment: @Servy, I've never come across these particular ownership "rules" (You say rules, I say guidelines). Do you have a reference please?

Comment: @Servy: The [Help Center says to edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) "Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. [...] Some common reasons to edit [include] - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages - to add related resources or hyperlinks". The edit history makes it clear which parts of a post represent the content of the post's original author, and which parts were added by others.

Comment: @JamesWebster The help center; the FAQ, the related posts linked to from them, etc.

Comment: @Servy, that's where I'm referencing, and I haven't seen anything, certainly nothing strict, that claims "posts are the property of the author, don't touch unless broken". I've found quite the opposite, there are plenty of sentences that I've interpreted to mean "Please add your own content if you can make it better". I quote those above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a high-rep user on ELL, I would have approved your edit.

One of the reasons is a default reason and the other is a custom one.

The default reason -

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of the post's owner.

Yes, someone who didn't actually look at the images might think this is the case but if you actually see the image and understand it, you can see that it clearly illustrates exactly what the text describes. This was an incorrect rejection.

This reason is for edits that actually change the answer to something very different to what it was. For example, if someone originally said "The answer is A" and you changed it to say "The answer is not A, it's B"... that's bad, and that's a valid rejection using this reason.

The custom reason -

> You should first leave a comment to the author of the Q asking his permission. The author has not disappeared, so there's a good chance he will reply.

This is written by someone who doesn't seem to understand one of the purposes of editing and who sees the post as inviolate. There's no need to ask for permission. If the OP doesn't like the edit, it can be rolled back. Simple as pie.

There's no reason to clutter up the comments to ask permission to add images and it's sort of silly to say "Hey, this would be awesome with some illustrative images to make it more easy to understand. Would you consider adding that?"... if you're willing to do it yourself instead.

---

So, I think you can see from the above that the answer to your question is **no**. Asking permission is unnecessary. The system is robust and well-built, so it's easy to return posts to earlier versions by rolling them back. Yes, edit reviews are useful for learning what sorts of edits are acceptable but they're not infallible.

I have brought this up on [ELL meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3330/lets-not-dissuade-users-from-adding-valuable-content-to-posts) and I encourage you to resubmit your edit request. Hopefully it will get better reception on a subsequent submission.

Answer (score 9):

If you think you can improve an answer (or a question), especially if it makes a substantial improvement, then I would encourage you to edit it.

I see no need to ask permission first. If you are "over-editing" then the frequency of edit rejections and rollbacks will let you know, and you can then adjust your editing behaviour to suit your community.

Answer (score -4):

Edits, especially suggested edits, are for improving the **format** of a post, not the **content**. Say somebody tried to do a numbered list but it didn't work, or they had a giant wall of text and it should be split into paragraphs. Fixing spelling mistakes and grammar issues are also in the realm of suggested edit work. But fixing content is not. The first comment is generated when people reject your edit for this reason. You tried to change the content. Don't do that.

The second comment is from someone who believes (it's not site policy) that if you commented on the post offering to edit in some relevant content, and the post owner commented say "sure, thanks" that the edit would be approved. They aren't necessarily correct, because edit-reviewers don't always read comments, but I suppose anything can happen.

Learn the difference between the two kinds of improving and you'll be less frustrated by the suggested edit process. For content improvement, if it's so minor that you don't think an answer of your own is warranted, this is a great use for comments. I often edit my own answers after people leave extra information in comments.

Comment: The Help Center says to edit "Any time you feel you can make the post better, and are inclined to do so. [...] Some common reasons to edit [include] - to correct minor mistakes or add addendums / updates as the post ages - to add related resources or hyperlinks". Is this wrong?